# Gitlab-runner Interactive Web Terminals not connected

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have installed successfully a gitlab-runner on a VM, and it is used by some of my projects. I would like to use the [Interactive Web Terminal](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/interactive_web_terminal/) to have a chance to debug when some pipeline fails.

I'm trying to configure my config.toml file, following [this docu of GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-session_server-section) but I'm not understanding which ip address I should use in the setting `listen_address`. Should it be the ip of the running machine? The docker container instance? Or what?

**Here is my current configuration:**

```
concurrent = 2
check_interval = 0
log_level = "panic"

[session_server]
  listen_address = "0.0.0.0:8093" #  listen on all available interfaces on port 8093
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "A test private repo"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = "myToken"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "alpine:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
  [runners.custom]
    run_exec = ""
```

**Screen of error I get**

[image]

I noticed that when I hit the 0.0.0.0:8093 address on the machine where the gitlab-runner is running I get this response:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your configuration should use:

```
[session_server]
   session_timeout = 1800
   listen_address = "0.0.0.0:8093"
   advertise_address = "<your runner IP/hostname>:8093"
```

> Should it be the ip of the running machine?

Yes

Comment: When I add the line:  `advertise_address = "runner_hostname:8093"` web terminal starts to work.

Comment: So the runner IP address should be available before creating the config? What about dynamic docker+machine instances?