# Gitlab-runner Interactive Web Terminal behind Apache Proxy

Tags: docker, terminal, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

### Summary

I'm currently trying to setup the nice Web-Terminal feature on my self-hosted Gitlab-Instance. But I can't get it running properly. Also debugging is a rather difficult task.

### Environment description/Steps to reproduce

Gitlab version: GitLab Community Edition 13.9.0
Gitlab runner on the same machine as Gitlab: Runs in a docker-container with multiple runners configured. Output of `docker ps` (port 8093 is forwarded correctly):

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS        PORTS                                                                                                                                                                                                                               NAMES
CONTAINERID    gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   15 hours ago   Up 12 hours   0.0.0.0:8093->8093/tcp                                                                                                                                                                                                              gitlab-runner2
```

The config.toml is placed in `/srv/gitlab-runner/config/config.toml` (from the [gitlab-docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html#option-1-use-local-system-volume-mounts-to-start-the-runner-container) and I added the following configuration (from the [gitlab-docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-session_server-section)):

```
[session_server]
  listen_address = "[::]:8093"
  advertise_address = "localhost:8093"
  session_timeout = 1800
```

The official docs state that the `advertise_address` is not needed necessarily and it falls back to the listen_address. Nevertheless I read in several issues here on that topic, that this *needs* to be the external IP/hostname, where the runners are accessible. In my case they do not need any external IP as they are running on the same machine. Nevertheless I also tried it with my static server-ip and the domain of my selfhosted gitlab without success.

Gitlab is running behind an Apache-Proxy. The [Gitlab-docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/integration/terminal.html#enabling-and-disabling-terminal-support) do not offer a lot information about how the proxy should be configured for the interactive terminals.

My current **Apache-config** for gitlab looks like this (gitlab is running on port 7777):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName git.example.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests     Off
    RewriteEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine On
    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

    <Location />
        ProxyPass http://localhost:7777/ nocanon
        ProxyPassReverse https://git.example.com/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:7777/
        Require all granted
    </Location>

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
    RewriteRule .* "wss:/localhost:7777/$1" [P,L]

    ProxyPass "*/terminal.ws" "wss://localhost:7777/"
    <Location */terminal.ws>
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
        RewriteRule ^/?(.*) "wss://localhost:7777/$1" [P,L]
     </Location>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName pages.example.com
    ServerAlias *.pages.example.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass "/" "http://127.0.0.1:8090/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://127.0.0.1:8090/

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8090%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]
</VirtualHost>
```

Here are my relevant changes in the **`gitlab.rb`**-file:

```
nginx['listen_addresses'] = ['0.0.0.0', "[::]"]
nginx['listen_port'] = 7777
nginx['listen_https'] = false
puma['port'] = 8081
external_url 'https://git.example.com'
pages_external_url "http://pages.example.com/"
gitlab_pages['enable'] = true
gitlab_pages['listen_proxy'] = "localhost:8090"

gitlab_pages['redirect_http'] = false
pages_nginx['enable'] = false
```

I also tried adding this to the `gitlab.rb` but I think this is the default configuration anyway:

```
nginx['proxy_set_headers'] = {
  "Host" => "$http_host_with_default",
  "X-Real-IP" => "$remote_addr",
  "X-Forwarded-For" => "$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for",
  "X-Forwarded-Proto" => "https",
  "X-Forwarded-Ssl" => "on",
  "Upgrade" => "$http_upgrade",
  "Connection" => "$connection_upgrade"
}
```

This is my `.gitlab/.gitlab-webide.yml` of the project, which I want to use:

```
terminal:
  image:
    name: python:latest
  script: sleep 60
```

I also tried to disable my firewall (ufw) and allowed connections on port `8093` without success.

### Actual behavior

Gitlab pages are working fine, also the configured runners are working fine in pipelines.
But when I click either the "Debug" option for running jobs or the Web-Terminal, a connection error occurs:

```
terminal.js:47 WebSocket connection to 'wss://git.example.com/user/project/-/jobs/JOB_ID/terminal.ws' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

But the Job for the Webterminal is actually running (the `sleep 60` line runs, after this the pipeline succeeded). I can view the log of the job at `https://git.example.com/user/project/-/jobs/JOB_ID`.

After searching a lot, I now don't know how to proceed - especially because I have no good debug-strategy.

#### Edit

I tried to connect with the server with `websocat wss://0.0.0.0:8094` which returns

```
websocat: WebSocket SSL error: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:../ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1915: (self signed certificate)
websocat: error running
```

When I ignore the self signed cert with `websocat -t -  ws-c:sh-c:'socat - ssl:0.0.0.0:8093,verify=0' --ws-c-uri=wss://echo.websocket.org` (some workaround for websocat) it returns the same error as in the WebIDE:

```
websocat: WebSocketError: Received unexpected status code (404 Not Found)
websocat: error running
```

The log of the gitlab-runner indicates that the server is listening - then I wonder, why I get a 404 response when I'm trying to connect. `docker logs gitlab-runner` returns:

```
All workers stopped. Can exit now                   builds=0
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=6 revision=775dd39d version=13.8.0
Starting multi-runner from /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml...  builds=0
Running in system-mode.                            
                                                   
Configuration loaded                                builds=0
listen_address not defined, metrics & debug endpoints disabled  builds=0
Session server listening                            address=[::]:8093 builds=0
```

The request header of terminal.ws looks like this:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Upgrade
Cookie: event_filter=all; sidebar_collapsed=false; diff_whitespace=0; collapsed_gutter=true; hide_auto_devops_implicitly_enabled_banner_10=false; hide_auto_devops_implicitly_enabled_banner_28=false; diff_view=inline; hide_auto_devops_implicitly_enabled_banner_9=false; pipeline_schedules_callout_dismissed=true; _ga=*; _fbp=*; _gid=*; __stripe_mid=*; known_sign_in=*; _gitlab_session=*
Host: git.example.com
Origin: https://git.example.com 
Pragma: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Key: *
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: terminal.gitlab.com
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Upgrade: websocket
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36 OPR/74.0.3911.107
```

### Expected behavior

The terminal should be visible in the browser or any outputs in any log-file.

#### Used GitLab Runner version

```
Version:      13.8.0
Git revision: 775dd39d
Git branch:   13-8-stable
GO version:   go1.13.8
Built:        2021-01-20T13:32:47+0000
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Related topics:

- [This issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/27609)
- [Web terminals / session server on gitlab.com with self-hosted runner on gke](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/web-terminals-session-server-on-gitlab-com-with-self-hosted-runner-on-gke/19485)
- [Gitlab-runner Interactive Web Terminals not connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57233524/gitlab-runner-interactive-web-terminals-not-connected)
- gitlab-org/gitlab-runner#3884
- gitlab-org/gitlab-runner#3713
- gitlab-org/gitlab#202213

Comment: Any solution? Struggling with the same issue